# File-counting without Directory.GetFiles() because of too long paths error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

It's about a progressbar that runs besides a file-import tool. Because I need to know how much files we have to import, I need to count them somehow. Normally I do that like this:

```
return new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

This doesn't work for me because I have to handle the `TooLongPathException`. And when counting them, the compiler tries to access the specific object which results in an Exception. In the fileimport-process it's already handled. I can just overlook the specific file.

Because I only need to count the files and don't have to do something with them, I'm looking for another solution to count some files in subfolders. Since I work with .net3.5, I can't use the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` method.

Comment: There is API methods you can call that may help which are `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` but i never used them for iterating directories as well. You can see the help about these method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/listing-the-files-in-a-directory). The path to long limit is a windows thing so i don't know if it will bypass the error or not. But i might help you find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

The library [Zeta Long Paths](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=zetalongpaths) is basically a wrapper around specific win32 functions which allow you to use paths longer than 260 characters. I would recommend using this or searching through the win32 documentation for the needed functions and then using p/invoke to make your own kind of wrapper.

Note that from .NET 4.6.2 and up .NET has support for larger paths if you ever decide to update your project to a newer .NET version.